# Retrofit convert multipart body back to file

Tags: android, multipartform-data, retrofit2

I am using multipart for uploading data to server. The problem is that the backend developer told me that the file I was uploading became corrupted during upload.

So is there any way to test those file locally? Like can I convert a file to multipart and then reconvert it to file to test it?

I am using Retrofit 2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> ask your backend developer whether he want file as binary or as base64 if it is image and then send file accordingly 
>   you can also log what data is being sent in body of your post

here is code to log data you are sending through retrofit

```
public class RetrofitClient {


private RetrofitClient() {
}




public static Retrofit getApiClient(String baseHost) {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
```

// set your desired log level
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

```
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
    httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();

            // Request customization: add request headers
            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .header(Util.HEADER_KEY, ""+Util.HEADER_VALUE); // <-- this is the important line

            Request request = requestBuilder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()

            .baseUrl(baseHost)

            .addConverterFactory(new NullOnEmptyConverterFactory())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build();


    return retrofit;
}
```

}